# Is there a way to join four data tables depend on date?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to join four data tables depend on date in order to view all patient details? Below are my tables with columns:

```
registration 
 (re_id,firstname,lastname,phone)

patientnotes 
 (paid,notes,re_id,tarehe)

laboratory 
 (labid,investigations,re_id,tarehe)

result 
 (rid,result,re_id,tarehe)
```

Comment: Yes, you can join unlimited tables according to your requirement

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can join as many tables as you want.  It looks like the common id between all your tables is the re_id, so use that to join across all records into a single row, and select the columns you want in the resulting table.

```
SELECT *
FROM registration
INNER JOIN patientnotes ON patientnotes.re_id = registration.re_id
INNER JOIN laboratory ON laboratory.re_id = registration.re_id
INNER JOIN result ON result.re_id = registration.re_id
```